# What is the full specification of the Console.ReadLine() method?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I know that namespaces allows assistance in avoiding name clashes between two
sets of codes. Namespaces also are used to keep your codes in order.
A good way is to use the hierarchical system, where most of the
general names are listed first at the top, then the most specific
names are listed as you go down the hierarchy list. Using namespace
also defines function when writing your code.

My questions is What is the full specification of the `Console.ReadLine()` method? Can we use the full specification of a method without being necessary to “use” its namespace?

Comment: System.Console.ReadLine is the full name and yes, we can use full name if you dont want to use using. You could have tried this on your own to find out its possible or not :).

Comment: Look into `using static` to get even more questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the keyword 'using' with namespaces. So if you have different namespaces declared in your project, you can use the 'using' directive to avoid writing out the namespace name. The full specification for `Console.ReadLine()` is `System.Console.Readline()`.